# SDL Transfer texture using SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm using SDL2 with `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` without OpenGL and I want to transfer/combine some Textures from my function to my main loop. So, I decided to change my Access type from `STREAMING` to `TARGET`, use `SDL_SetRenderTarget` with `SDL_RenderCopy` and again put the Access type to `STREAMING`, but when I preview it with the `SDL_RenderPresent` not is showing the sended texture.

Here is my function to Open the textures:

```
TUserFunc(
    void, OpenTTF, Reference font, int32_t align, int32_t x, int32_t y, Reference txt, int32_t scl)
{    
    int tgt_w = g_w;
    int tgt_h = g_h; 
 
    TTF_Font * ttfFont = TTF_OpenFont(pu->refToAstr(CP_THREAD_ACP, font).c_str(), scl);
    if(ttfFont == nullptr) { 
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "SDL ERROR", "Error cargando la direccion de las fuentes", NULL);
        quitGame();
    } 
    
    SDL_Surface * surfaceText = TTF_RenderText_Blended(ttfFont, (pu->refToAstr(CP_THREAD_ACP, txt).c_str()), color);
    if(surfaceText == nullptr){
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "SDL ERROR", "Error creando Superficie", NULL);
        quitGame();
    } 
    
    textureText = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(g_renderer,surfaceText); 
    if(textureText == nullptr){
        SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR, "SDL ERROR", "Error creando Texturas", NULL);
        quitGame();
    } 

    SDL_Rect rectangle;
    rectangle.x = x;
    rectangle.y = y;
    rectangle.w = surfaceText->w;
    rectangle.h = surfaceText->h;

//The Problem Start from here

    unlockTarget(); 
    g_target = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, tgt_w, tgt_h);

    SDL_SetRenderTarget(g_renderer, g_target);
    SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, textureText, NULL, &rectangle);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(g_renderer, NULL);
     
    g_target = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, tgt_w, tgt_h);
    lockTarget();
}
```

`lockTarget()` and `unlockTarget()` it's for a simple way to lock and unlock the texture, and how you can see, I use the `CreateTexture` to change to `TARGET`, put my `SetRenderTarget` and `RenderCopy` and again use the `CreateTexture` to change back to `STREAMING`

And this is my main loop to show the graphics:

```
TUserFunc(void, Flip)
{       

    if(g_target){
        unlockTarget();
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, g_target, nullptr, nullptr); 
        lockTarget();
    }     
    SDL_RenderPresent(g_renderer);
}
```

but if I add this, the texture is showed, but not same texture, I mean, not is combined with `g_target`

```
TUserFunc(void, Flip)
{       

    if(g_target){
        unlockTarget();
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, g_target, nullptr, nullptr); 
        lockTarget();
    }    
    if(textureText){
        unlockTarget();
        SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, textureText, nullptr, nullptr); 
        lockTarget();
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(g_renderer);
}
```

Here you can see the other functions to have a better view about the problem:

```
TUserFunc(bool, Init...)
{
...
        // This is the main and unique call to g_target
    g_target = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888,
            SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, w, h);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(g_target, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
...
}

void lockTarget()
{
    if(g_target) SDL_LockTexture(g_target, nullptr, (void**)&g_pix, &g_pitch);
    if(textureText) SDL_LockTexture(textureText, nullptr, (void**)&g_pix, &g_pitch);
}

void unlockTarget()
{
    if(g_target) SDL_UnlockTexture(g_target);
    if(textureText) SDL_UnlockTexture(textureText);
}
```

Comment: Who told you that you could use `SDL_CreateTexture` to change a texture's access pattern? There are several things wrong with your code but that's probably the main issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### The problem

This can't work:

```
unlockTarget(); 
g_target = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, tgt_w, tgt_h);

SDL_SetRenderTarget(g_renderer, g_target);
SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, textureText, NULL, &rectangle);
SDL_SetRenderTarget(g_renderer, NULL);
 
g_target = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, tgt_w, tgt_h);
lockTarget();
```

You create a texture, render another one onto it, and then proceed to get rid of its pointer and create a new one.

`SDL_CreateTexture`, as its name implies, creates a texture.

With this line:

```
g_target = SDL_CreateTexture(g_renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ARGB8888, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, tgt_w, tgt_h);
```

You are essentially throwing away whatever `g_target` held and replaces it with a new, empty texture with `STREAMING` access.

> I use the `CreateTexture` to change to `TARGET`, put my `SetRenderTarget` and `RenderCopy` and again use the `CreateTexture` to change back to `STREAMING`

This simply not how it works. You can't change a texture's access mode once it has been created. All that `SDL_CreateTexture` does is creating yet another texture.

As a result, all you do is leaking memory and get non-working code.

### The clean solution

An `SDL_Texture`, according to [the documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Texture) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230802221223/https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Texture)), is:

> A structure that contains an efficient, driver-specific representation of pixel data.

You aren't supposed to do anything with `SDL_Texture`s besides rendering them or rendering other textures onto it.
Changing their access mode in real time is not possible.

If you really need to render textures on top of others and then access their pixel data, then use [`SDL_Surface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Surface)s ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230802221545/https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_Surface)):

> A structure that contains a collection of pixels used in software blitting.

You can blit those on top of others as well, using [`SDL_BlitSurface`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_BlitSurface). Plus, you can access `SDL_Surface`s' pixel data for further editing.

And only THEN, where you are DONE touching to pixel data, convert it into a texture using `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` and render it.

It might be slower than trying to mess directly with textures, but at least it works and is meant to be done.

Sure, `STREAMING` mode exists on textures for a reason, but all you can do with it is hacky trickery to get things poorly done where using surfaces would have been much better.

And besides, you *can't* change a texture's access mode from `TARGET` to `STREAMING` as I have already said, so you don't really have a choice here. You need to use surfaces.

Comment: FYI, a downvote doesn't denote an answer is "wrong", it means that the user didn't find it helpful or useful (as noted in the tooltip).

Comment: Indeed, let me reformulate then: I'm always open to improving my answers, but I can't if I am not being told why it isn't helpful. I believe that my answer solves OP's problem, as it demonstrates why they ask for cannot be done and gives an alternative for them to do what they need.

Comment: All up/down votes are anonymous by design. There are plenty of duplicates about this on [meta.se].

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I tried your solution and I was able to do some tricky results with that, thank you so much for the help! I wish to up vote but I'm still in a low level in this comunnity,

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm glad to hear that my answer helped you.